# Entity Framework DbContext filtered query for count is extremely slow using a variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, query-optimization

Using an ADO.NET entity data model I've constructed two queries below against a table containing 1800 records that has just over 30 fields that yield staggering results.

```
// Executes slowly, over 6000 ms
int count = context.viewCustomers.AsNoTracking()
                   .Where(c => c.Cust_ID == _custID).Count();

// Executes instantly, under 20 ms
int count = context.viewCustomers.AsNoTracking()
                   .Where(c => c.Cust_ID == 625).Count();
```

I see from the database log that Entity Framework provides that the queries are almost identical except that the filter portion uses a parameter. Copying this query into SSMS and declaring & setting this parameter there results in a near instant query so it doesn't appear to be on the database end of things.

Has anyone encountered this that can explain what's happening? I'm at the mercy of a third party control that adds this command to the query in an attempt to limit the number of rows returned, getting the count is a must. This is used for several queries so a generic solution is needed. It is unfortunate it doesn't work as advertised, it seems to only make the query take 5-10 times as long as it would if I just loaded the entire view into memory. When no filter is used however, it works like a dream.

Use of these components includes the source code so I can change this behavior but need to consider which approaches can be used to provide a reusable solution.

Comment: My guess your table does not has `Index` on column `Cust_ID`. May be you can check and reconfirm that.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention about design details of your model but if you only want to have count of records based on condition, then this can be optimized by only counting the result set based on one column. For example,

```
    int count = context.viewCustomers.AsNoTracking().Where(c => c.Cust_ID == _custID).Count();
```

If you design have 10 columns, and based on above statement let say 100 records have been returned, then against every record result set contains 10 columns' data which is of not use.

You can optimize this by only counting result set based on single column.

```
   int count = context.viewCustomers.AsNoTracking().Where(c => c.Cust_ID == _custID).Select(x=>new {x.column}).Count();
```

Other optimization methods, like using async variants of count [`CountAsync`](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/) can be used.